# Ansibles 'lookup' returns different type when template is valid json, how can I prevent that?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible template, that looks like this (not working version):

```
data:
{% for file in files %}
{{ file.name | indent(2, true) }}: |
{{ lookup('template', file.src_path ) | indent(4, true) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works wonderfull, if the template at `file.src_path` is not a json file.

But when it is a json file,I get:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'"
```

I assume, this is because `lookup('template', file.src_path )` suddenly returns a dict, not a string.

I could not do something like this:

```
{{ lookup('template', file.src_path ) | to_json | indent(4, true) }}
```

But that will give an unwanted result, if the output of `lookup` is not an object/dict.

Comment: The template lookup has a parameter [`convert_data`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_lookup.html#parameter-convert_data), which looks like it could solve your problem, but I could not test it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have few options:

You can check if it's a json file, and do another treatment, or you can check the result (dict, list, string...). Some examples here: [Ansible: Check if a variable contains a list or dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729009/ansible-check-if-a-variable-contains-a-list-or-dictionary)